# Why aren't my boolean variables being recognised? - Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a pizza ordering application for my college course and am working through the code. Being rather noobish when it comes to coding, I've had problems with Eclipse telling me that two boolean variables aren't being used, when I know for a fact that they are.

My variables have stupid names, but they're easy for me to remember while writing the program. For some reason my Topping and DoubleCheeseBoolean variables aren't being recognised in the code even though when I use them there's no errors appear.

This is the entirety of what I currently have, could someone please just tell me what I need to do to fix my boolean issues.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Creates Scanner

    // Variables
    String DoubleCheeseString;
    Boolean DoubleCheeseBoolean;

    Boolean Topping;
    int Topping1;
    int Topping2;

    int Attempts = 3;

    double Cost = 00.00;

    // Program
    // Asks the user if they would like a double cheese pizza
        System.out.println("Would you like double cheese for 50p more? (Answer with either 'yes' or 'no')");
        DoubleCheeseString = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (DoubleCheeseString == "yes") {
            DoubleCheeseBoolean = true;
        } else if (DoubleCheeseString == "no") {
            DoubleCheeseBoolean = false;
        } else {

        }

        // Asks the user if they would like a topping on their pizza
        Attempts = 3;
        while (Attempts > 0) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to add a topping to your pizza?");
            System.out.println("The first topping cost £1.00 and up to two more can be added for 50p each");
            System.out.println("(Answer with 'yes' or 'no')");
            if (keyboard.hasNext("yes")) {
                Topping = true;
            } else if (keyboard.hasNext("No")) {
                Topping = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter 'yes' or 'no'. Anything else is invalid.");
                System.out.println("You have " + Attempts + " left before the program closes.");
                if (Attempts == 0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
```

Comment: Please, don't post the entire program. Isolate the issue and post only the relevant code. That's just too much to read

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using variables and assigning to them are very different things.

eg: Here, I assign the variable but not use it.

```
int x = 3;
```

eg: Here, I use the variable.

```
if (x == 3) { // do something }
```

In your case, you're not using the variables at all, and all you've done is assign values.

**Solutions:** If you really want to get rid of the warnings, you can print them out or something and that will resolve the issue. Note that unused variable warnings can be ignored without problems. Or, you can just delete them and their assignments, since it wasn't being used anyways.

On the off chance that you're actually going to be using those values later, just leave the warning alone and it should self correct itself when you start to use it.

For future reference, please use `.equals()` to compare your strings. When you compare strings using `==` the result will nearly always be false.

You may also want to include an else block when you're testing yes/no input, in case the user enters invalid input. Remember: Never trust user input!

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the most informative of the lot so far. I know I could have run the program without them, but I just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything wrong with the code. All the other variables I've used in the code didn't return any kind of error and I couldn't understand exactly what I'd done differently. Again thank you very much, I didn't understand that I was just assigning them and not using them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see them being used anywhere... you're assigning values to them, but never reading them. Eclipse will complain about this (like you're seeing).

Answer (score 0):

There are certain branch conditions in your code that will not set the `Topping` boolean.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    if (keyboard.hasNext("yes")) {
        Topping = true;
    } else if (keyboard.hasNext("No")) {
        Topping = false;
    } else {
```

So if the user enters something other than "yes" or "No", the variable will never be used. Same thing with this code:

```
    if(DoubleCheeseString=="yes"){
        DoubleCheeseBoolean=true;
    }else if(DoubleCheeseString=="no"){
        DoubleCheeseBoolean=false;
    }else{

    }
```

You can just initialize your variable with `False` to fix the warnings.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, but not the answer to his Q.